# (Android) Create an application with home screen widget

Tags: android, widget

Do you know how to create a application with a home screen widget?

in fact , i want create an application and a widget which will be  deployed in the home screen.

the application allow to configure the widget and several another things.

the all will be in one application and will be deployed in same time on the the mobile.

Can you help me , i didn't found how to do that on the web?

Thanks by advance

Comment: This site is for specific questions. Not free tutors/doing your homework.

Answer (score 1):

App widgets are covered in [the Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).